# Android Imageview is drawing new image over previous image

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawable

I want to change the image displayed on an imageview at every touch event. The code below accomplishes that.

```
public class TelephoneFragment extends Fragment {

ImageView telephoneImageView;

@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.telephone_fragment,
        container, false);
    telephoneImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.telephoneImageView);
    telephoneImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                telephoneImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.telephone_clicked));
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                telephoneImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.telephone));
            }
            return true;    
        }
    });
    return view;
  }
```

}

There is a problem however though that when I change the orientation of the phone, and try touching the image again, the new image is drawn over the previous image, that is the previous image is still visible in the background. Can someone guide me as to what is happening? Thanks.

--I tried using setImageResource() as well instead of setImageDrawable but the problem persists.

Comment: Have u tried setImageBitmap

Comment: Ok, I'll try that as well..

Comment: setImageBitMap gave the same problem as well.

Comment: So, I just realized that an activity is restarted when the orientation changes, i guess this could have something to do with what i'm seeing?

Comment: then add android:configChanges="orientation"

Comment: that still did not solve the problem.

Comment: Ok so doing this -- android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" has finally solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following, just before you set the second drawable.

```
telephoneImageView.setImageResource(0);
```

I have not tried the above, but if it doesn't work also try:

```
telephoneImageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Also try specifying the imageview as invisible, then set it back to visible again. This might trigger a redraw. You could also try a combination of the above and maybe try telephoneImageView.invalidate().

Comment: unfortunately, both don't work, it seems once the orientation changes, the previous images somehow become fixed on the screen

Comment: What is happening is that ImageView is not erasing its canvas probably for performance reasons. So what you need to try and find is a method of forcing it to redraw. Maybe a combination of the above and telephoneImageView.invalidate(). I'm not sure without trying myself. Hope that helps.

Comment: alright, thanks..android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" seems to have done the trick...though i'm not sure why and it feels like a hack...